# If a convex function is divided by a linear function, what will it be?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I have a convex function $f(x)$ and a linear function $g(x)$. Is $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ still convex? If it is not, can I use the techniques in convex optimization to optimize $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$?

Comment: Have you at least tried an example like $f(x) = e^x$ and $g(x) = x$?

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=x^4$ is a convex function, and $g(x)=x$ is linear, but $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = x^3$ which is not convex

Comment: Thank you very much. So if I have a fractional function that may not be convex, can I add some constraints or do something else to make it able to solve with convex optimization?